# How to provide an expression as parameter in `PreparedStatement`

Tags: java, prepared-statement

This table is representing a **radio button**.

```
id    | radio_id    | value    | is_selected
------|-------------|----------|-------------
1     | 10          | one      | false
2     | 10          | two      | false
3     | 10          | three    | true
```

I could run following query to select another radio.

```
UPDATE TABLE radios SET is_selected = (id = 1) WHERE radio_id = 10
```

Using this query I was also assuring that only 1 radio box is selected.

```
id    | radio_id    | value    | is_selected
------|-------------|----------|-------------
1     | 10          | one      | true
2     | 10          | two      | false
3     | 10          | three    | false
```

But I am unable to do the same thing with `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE radios SET is_selected = ? WHERE radio_id = ?");
ps.setObject(1, "(id = 1)");
ps.setInt(2, 10);
```

But then I am getting error that String cannot be converted to boolean.
How to provide an expression as parameter in prepared statement.

Comment: `UPDATE TABLE` ? (first time I see that)

Comment: Don't understand that part ``is_selected = (id = 1)`` I would assume you want to set a boolean here.... Basically that's what your error message is telling you... You try to set a String ``(id=1)`` but a boolean is expected.

Comment: Why are you keeping a GUI model in a database? Are you only planning on supporting one user?

Comment: You probably misunderstood the point of prepared statements. You can only replace what is seen as *literals* in the SQL with parameters. You cannot substitude keywords, symbols or expressions. In your original query only `1` and `10` are literals. `(id = 1)` is an expression that gives boolean results.

Comment: @EJP It is a part of a project in which user can create his own fields. And radios are one of those fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
    con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE radios SET is_selected = (id = ?) WHERE radio_id = ?");
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setInt(2, 10);
```

Comment: Actually query is created dynamically in some other class. I am only supposed to pass key-value pair and name of table with `where` i.e. field_name-field_value pair and table name with `where`. So I cannot do that.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the method that creates the query?

Comment: You might consider to change the design of the method to have only values as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
con.prepareStatement("UPDATE radios SET is_selected = (id = 1) WHERE radio_id = ?");
```

Comment: Actually query is created dynamically in some other class. I am only supposed to pass key-value pair and name of table with `where` i.e. field_name-field_value pair and table name with `where`. So I cannot do that.